# How to prevent no-return-assign error?

Tags: javascript

I do get an `no-return-assign` linting error for this reduce statement:

```
array.reduce((acc, { name }) => (acc[name] = 1, acc), {})
```

I'm expecting to get an object result, which I'll use as fields parameter for my mongoDB find request.

How do I prevent the error?

Comment: What are you planning to do with the result of your reduce operation? Nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`no-return-assign` is there to prevent you from accidentally assigning in a return statement when you meant to compare (i.e. `=` vs `==`). It applies here because of syntax sugar - your code is functionally equivalent to this:

```
array.reduce((acc, { name }) => {
    return (acc[name] = 1, acc);
}, {});
```

There's three ways you could get around this.

You could separate out the assignment and return in your code, like so:

```
array.reduce((acc, { name }) => {
    acc[name] = 1;
    return acc;
}, {});
```

You could configure ESLint to ignore `no-return-assign` when it occurs in parentheses using the [`unless-parens`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-return-assign#except-parens) setting.

Or, you could disable the lint altogether.

Personally, I would recommend the first option, as it makes the code clearer.